# The homology cycles of the diagonal in the product of a manifold with itself

Tags: algebraic-topology

For simplicity, let us first focus on the torus case. Suppose $T$ is a torus (i.e. $S^1 \times S^1$). Let us choose an orientation of $T$, and a usual basis $A_1,A_2$ of $H_1(T,\mathbb{Z})$ that corresponds to the two $S^1$ in $S^1 \times S^1$, e.g right hand rule. Then the homology group $H_2(T \times T,\mathbb{Z})$ is given by
\begin{equation}
H_2(T \times T,\mathbb{Z})=(H_0(T,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H_2(T,\mathbb{Z})) \oplus (H_1(T,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H_1(T,\mathbb{Z})) \oplus (H_2(T,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H_0(T,\mathbb{Z})).
\end{equation}
The diagonal $\Delta$ of $T \times T$ is given by points of the form $(x,x) \in T \times T$. It defines a homology cycle that is in $H_1(T,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H_1(T,\mathbb{Z})$. Is there any direct (or easy way) to show what is the homology class of $\Delta$? E.g.
\begin{equation}
\Delta \sim A_1 \times A_2-A_2 \times A_1?
\end{equation}

What about its generalization to $n$-dimensional orientated manifold?

Comment: Yes. There is always such a description. The cohomological statement can be found in Characteristic Classes by Milnor & Stasheff, Theorem 11.11. The homological statement then follows by Poincaré duality.

Comment: @juandiegorojas Thank you very much.